What is the logic of trailingstop of strategy.exit() in Pinescript?
I was coding a strategy that was found in the TradingView community.
This simple strategy is the Bollinger band, and slow stochastic.
What I was confused is that what is the logic of trailing-stop of strategy.exit().
I remember that entry and exit orders are done in the strategy script after the bar is finished.
But in TradingCode(https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/strategy-exit-function/), there is a sentence, "Once the market touches that level" in 'trail_price', and "When that profit amount is hit" in 'trail_point' part.
does 'Once' mean that trailing-stop activates when high or low hits the activation level, even if the bar is not finished?
Below is my strategy code. I tested this strategy in a 30m chart, and I found that the exit order activates even if the bar is not closed.
Can anybody tell me (1) why the exit happens before the bar closes? (2) ATR value that is used for strategy.exit() trailing stop? is ATR value the current bar value (which is not certain because the bar is not closed), or 1 bar back from the current bar value?
Refer to my code.
//@version=5
strategy("Bollinger y Estocástico con Trailing Stop", overlay=true,process_orders_on_close = true)

// Parámetros de entrada
lengthBB = input(20, title="Longitud BB")
stdDevBB = input(2, title="Desviación Estándar BB")
kLength = input(14, title="Longitud K Estocástico")
dLength = input(3, title="Longitud D Estocástico")
smooth = input(3, title="Suavizado Estocástico")
atrLength = input(14, title="Longitud ATR")
trailStopATRMultiple = input(1.5, title="Multiplicador ATR para Trailing Stop")
StochOption=input.string("Fast", "Stochastic Option",options = ["Fast","Slow"])
stochOverbought=input(80,"Overbought")
stochOversold=input(20,"Oversold")

// Cálculos
[basisBB, upperBB, lowerBB] = ta.bb(close, lengthBB, stdDevBB)
stochFast = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, kLength), dLength)
stochSlow = ta.sma(ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, kLength), dLength),smooth)
stoch = StochOption=="Fast" ? stochFast : stochSlow
atr = ta.atr(atrLength)

// Condiciones de trading
longCondition = close < lowerBB and stoch < stochOversold
shortCondition = close > upperBB and stoch > stochOverbought

// Ejecutar operaciones
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Trailing Stop
strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Long", trail_points = atr * trailStopATRMultiple,
 trail_offset=atr * trailStopATRMultiple)
strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Short", trail_points = atr * trailStopATRMultiple,
 trail_offset=atr * trailStopATRMultiple)

//Stop loss for worst case
if strategy.position_size > 0
    if low < low[bar_index-strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1)] - 5*atr[bar_index-strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1)]
        strategy.close("Long")

if strategy.position_size < 0
    if high > high[bar_index-strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1)] + 5*atr[bar_index-strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades - 1)]
        strategy.close("Short")

I found TradingCode, which is manual of how to code Pinescript. But I couldn't understand and confused about what that writing meant.
